# jFrame поверх другого jFrame

Tags: java

Добрый вечер! Есть проблема. Имеется 2-а jFrame. Необходимо расположить jFrame таким образом, чтобы при запуске он был всегда поверх другого jFrame. Работаю на старой Java - а точнее 1.4.2. Вариант `setAlwaysOnTop(true)` - не работает, по очевидным причинам.

Вот моя программа. После компиляции можно увидеть что фрейм с текстовым полем прячется под главный фрейм. Необходимо чтобы он(фрейм с текстовым полем) был при старте сверху. Буду благодарен за помощь.

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*; 
import java.awt.color.*; 
import java.util.*; 
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.text.*;

public class pt extends JFrame { // класс pt называют прямым наследником класса JFrame

private JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4, 2, 2));

/*Главное меню JMenuBar - компонент графического интерфейса Java Swing*/

private JMenuBar menu = null;
private final String fileItems[] = new String []{"New", "Statistic", "Exit"};
private static Random generator = new Random(); // генератор случайных чисел
private int[][] numbers = new int[4][4];
public TimerLabel tl = new TimerLabel();
public JTextFieldDemo test = new JTextFieldDemo();

public pt() {
    setTitle("Пятнашки"); //Заголовок окна

    setSize (300, 300); // Задаем размеры окна приложения
    setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Окно приложения центрируется относительно экрана

    setResizable(true); // задаем возможность растягивать окно
    createMenu(); //инициализируем меню
    setJMenuBar(menu); // добавляем панель меню к окну
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // закрываем программу при закрытии окна

    Container container = getContentPane(); 
    init();
    panel.setDoubleBuffered(true);
    panel.setBackground(Color.white); // устанавливаем цвет фона
    container.add(panel); // добавление компонентов в контейнер
    repaintField();
    //setNik();
    menu.add(tl);
    Border solidBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1); // создаем границу черного цвета
    Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 12); // задаем тип шрифта, и его размер
    tl.setBorder(solidBorder); // устанавливаем границу
    tl.setFont(font); // устанавливаем тип текста
    tl.setForeground(Color.RED); // Устанавливаем цвет текста
    test.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

public void init() { // описание метода init
    int[] invariants = new int[16]; // инициализируем массив с именем invariants из 16 елементов - лт 0 до 15

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { // перебираем елементы i от 0 до 3
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) { // перебираем елементы j от 0 до 3
            numbers[i][j] = 0; // указываем что перебор в цыкле начинаеться с нулевого елемента
            invariants[i*4 + j] = 0; // определяем какой из 16 елементов будет = 0
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++) { // перебираем елементы i от 1 до 15
        int k; //обьявляем переменную k типа int
        int l; //обьявляем переменную l типа int
        do { // цыкл с послеусловием
            k = generator.nextInt(100) % 4; // переменной k присваиваем произвольное число от 0 до 100 деленное по модулю на 4
            l = generator.nextInt(100) % 4; // переменной l присваиваем произвольное число от 0 до 100 деленное по модулю на 4
        }
        while (numbers[k][l] != 0); // до тех пор пока двумерный массив numbers не равен 0
        numbers[k][l] = i; // присваиваем двумерному массиву numbers значение i в цикле от 1 до 15
        invariants[k*4+l] = i; // определяем позиции всех елементов кроме 0 на сетке
    }

    boolean change = true; // в булевую переменную change заносим значение true
    int counter = 1; // инициализируем переменную counter типа int и присваеваем ей 1
    while (change) {
        change = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            if (invariants[i] != i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
                    if (invariants[j] == i) {
                        int temp = invariants[i];
                        invariants[i] = invariants[j];
                        invariants[j] = temp;
                        change = true;
                        counter++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (counter % 2 != 0) {
        int temp = numbers[0][0];
        numbers[0][0] = numbers[3][3];
        numbers[3][3] = temp;
    }
}

// класс для создания таймера и вывода его в JLabel
public class TimerLabel extends JLabel {
    private DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("00"); // задаем формат вывода секундомера
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private TimerTask timerTask;

    public TimerLabel () 
    {
        restartTimer();
    }

    public void restartTimer()
    {
        stopTimer();
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            private volatile int time = -1;     
            /*определение переменной с ключевым словом volatile(«изменчивый») означает, 
            что значение переменной будет изменяться разными потоками.*/
            public void run() {
                time++;
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
                {
                    public void run(){
                        int t = time;
                        TimerLabel.this.setText(decimalFormat.format(t / 60) + ":" + decimalFormat.format(t % 60));
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000); //указываем задержку и период
    }

    public void stopTimer() 
    {
        if (timerTask != null)
            timerTask.cancel();
    }
}

public void repaintField() {  //метод расстановки кнопок со значениями на сетке
    panel.removeAll();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            JButton button = new JButton(Integer.toString(numbers[i][j]));
            button.setFocusable(false);
            panel.add(button);
            button.setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(0.1059322f, 0.5221239f, 0.8862745f)); // устанавливаем цвет кнопок
            if (numbers[i][j] == 0) {  
                button.setVisible(false); // сокрытие нулевого елемента массива
            } else
                button.addActionListener(new ClickListener());
        }
    }

    panel.validate();
}

public class JTextFieldDemo extends JFrame {

    //Class Declarations
    JTextField jtfText1;
    String disp = "";
    TextHandler handler = null;
    //Constructor
    public JTextFieldDemo() {
        super("Игрок");
        Container container = getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jtfText1 = new JTextField(15);
        container.add(jtfText1);
        handler = new TextHandler();
        jtfText1.addActionListener(handler);
        setSize(200, 100);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    //Inner Class TextHandler
    private class TextHandler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == jtfText1) {
                disp = "text1 : " + e.getActionCommand();
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, disp);
        }
    }   
}

public boolean checkWin() { //метод проверки выигрыша
    boolean status = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (i == 3 && j > 2) //проверка на то что последняя ячейка в сетке пустая
                break;
            if (numbers[i][j] != i * 4 + j + 1) { //проверка на соотвествие элементам массива координатам в сетке
                status = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return status;
}

private void createMenu() {
    menu = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");

    for (int i = 0; i < fileItems.length; i++) {
        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(fileItems[i]);
        JSeparator separator = new JSeparator();
        item.setActionCommand(fileItems[i].toLowerCase());
        item.addActionListener(new NewMenuListener());
        fileMenu.add(item);
        fileMenu.add(separator);
    }
    menu.add(fileMenu);
}

private class NewMenuListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        if ("exit".equals(command)) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if ("statistic".equals(command)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ВЫ ВЫИГРАЛИ!", "Поздравляем", 1);
        }
        if ("new".equals(command)) {
            init();
            repaintField();
            tl.restartTimer();
        }
    }
}

private class ClickListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
        button.setVisible(false);
        String name = button.getText();
        change(Integer.parseInt(name));
    }
}

public void change(int num) { // передаем в качестве входящих параметров метода change переменную num типа int
    int i = 0, j = 0; // присваиваем перменным i и j типа int значение равное 0
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) { // перебираем елементы k от 0 до 3
        for (int l = 0; l < 4; l++) { // перебираем елементы l от 0 до 3
            if (numbers[k][l] == num) { // если массив numbers[k][l] равный переменной num то,
                i = k; // переменную i приравниваем переменной k
                j = l; // переменную j приравниваем переменной l
            }
        }
    }

    /*реализация логики сдвигов кнопок на сетке 4 Х 4*/
    //сдвиг вверх по строкам
    if (i > 0) { // условие отвечающее за то можно ли сдвинуть кнопку по строке
        if (numbers[i - 1][j] == 0) { //сравниваем значение координат элемента массива с кнопкой которая в текущем массиве равна нулю
            numbers[i - 1][j] = num; //присваиваем переменной num значение координат элемента массива 
            numbers[i][j] = 0; //присваеваем нулевой элемент массива в ячейку которая перед этим смещалась в ноль
        }
    }
    //сдвиг вниз по строкам
    if (i < 3) {
        if (numbers[i + 1][j] == 0) {
            numbers[i + 1][j] = num;
            numbers[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    //сдвиг влево по столбцам
    if (j > 0) {
        if (numbers[i][j - 1] == 0) {
            numbers[i][j - 1] = num;
            numbers[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    //сдвиг вправо по столбцам
    if (j < 3) {
        if (numbers[i][j + 1] == 0) {
            numbers[i][j + 1] = num;
            numbers[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    repaintField();
    if (checkWin()) {
        tl.stopTimer();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ВЫ ВЫИГРАЛИ!", "Поздравляем", 1);
        init();
        repaintField();
        setVisible(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    JFrame app = new pt();
    app.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: Может скажешь саму проблему, что бы можно было придумать другой вариант, а то пока нече не придумал, разве что эти 2а фрейма хранить в 3м и внутри их контролировать

Answer (score 2):

поменяйте базовый класс для "2-а jFrame" на JDialog вместо JFrame, и сделайте диалог модальным.

UPDATE: "варианты":

а я попробовал так:

```
    public JTextFieldDemo ( final Frame parent )
    {
        // попробуйте еще разные константы для типа модальности    
        super ( parent, "Игрок", ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL ) ;
    ...

    test = new JTextFieldDemo ( this ) ;
    //test.setLocationRelativeTo ( null ) ;
```

Comment: Я преобразовал класс JTextFieldDemo так как ты сказал. Пока результат остался таким же. Вот что я добавил и преобразовал:  
    public class JTextFieldDemo extends JDialog  
    setModal(true);

Comment: для чего вам нужно первое окно которое отображается? только для того чтоб ввести имя пользователя? если так тогда вам вообще не надо ничего придумывать с 2мя окнами. сначала в коде вызываете:

    JOptionPane.showInputDialog ( message )

а потом уже после него ваше основное окно игры. и передаете ему данные из диалога.

Comment: из первого окна необходимо будет передавать данные в xml файл по нажатию на кнопку "ок" которую я еще просто не добавил на поле. А после передачи, при наджатии на элементе меню "statistic" должно появиться окно с результатами - то есть с именем игрока.
Если есть предложения по упрощению идеи - я открыт для предложений

Comment: я думал вам просто надо ввести имя пользователя перед началом игры, в этом случае стоит использовать стандартный диалог. а кнопку для просмотра статистики лучше конечно же сделать на основной форме, после чего собственно будет считыватся xml файл. а запись статистики после окончания игры (или при закрытии окна).

проще было бы если б вы описали "бизнес-задачу" а не конкретный "камень" о который вы споткнулись, в таком случае можна было бы предлагать более конкретно по теме

Comment: Я иду поэтапно. На данный момент меня интересует только один вопрос - как сделать так что бы при старте программы диалог был всегда сверху программы.